# Symfony 3.4 injection of service in controller action

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

services.yml

```
services:
  _defaults:
          autowire: true
          autoconfigure: true
          public: true
```

Controller:

```
 /**
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(ContactService $contactService)
    {
```

Error

```
:indexAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$contactService" argument.
```

What i should do to this example work (auto inject service to controller method)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `services.yaml` file, you're missing 2 things:

```
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'

App\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/Controller'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

The first line tells Symfony to make classes in src/ available to be used as services. This creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name.

For the second line, controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html

If you're not using the new Symfony Flex directory structure and you're still using bundles, the config is a little different:

```
AppBundle\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'

AppBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html

Comment: Can you give the source documentation for services from action methods? :)

Comment: What is example for vendor bundles - resource: '../../vendor/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/Controller' - dont work

Comment: Your example dont work - for my, this work 
       resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'

this dont work resource: '../src/AppBundle/Controller' 

and for vendor - i cannot find way to work example : resource: 'vendor/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/Controller'

Comment: @GregHmhmm Did you adapted the namespace as well ? `AppBundle\Controller\: resource: '../src/AppBundle/Controller'`